# CSS after table layout a big space

Tags: css

I am trying and fix this issue [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9aR/1/).

After my css table the last line `Reviews powered by Yelp` a big gap shows.

What I am trying and accomplish is remove the gap between the table and the footer line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a `height` option to your ticker -

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#ticker_yrtwidget-3').vTicker({
        speed: 2500000000000,
        pause: 60000000,
        height: '150px',  
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: false,
        direction: 'up',
        showItems: 2
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9aR/3/).

Your jQuery ticker was setting a custom height to the generated ticker div (which was ~292px in my browser). The gap was being caused by this. I've just specified a custom height so that the gap becomes smaller.

You could also set up a custom CSS class and define your desired height there, and then assign that class to your generated ticker. This approach might be even better (from a maintainability point of view) if your jQuery ticker supports CSS class configuration.

Comment: Would you actually be able to overcome it so it adjust accordingly to the browser windows size and height of quantity of text? (give the jQuery function no height just "use the space it needs" follow with the "footer"

Comment: @Flavio_D: Probably not, as the jQuery plugin (assuming that it's a plugin) seems to set a custom calculated height to the generated div. The best that you could do is probably give it a percentage height maybe, instead of an absolute hard-coded pixel value. Alternatively, you could also try by setting the height to `auto`.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed: yes, I just noticed that it is calculated, it's based on how many `<li>` and the space it haswith the browser window, I had the `showItems: 2` set to 2, so it was multiplying the `<li>` height by 2, since I was  displaying only 1 `<li>` the "space" appeared, to fix the issue, I can either add a second `li` or set the `showItems` to 1. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `ticker_yrtwidget-3` element has a manual height of `256px;` set. The footer (last line) comes after that.

Remove the height in your CSS.

This thing is very easy to spot with a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Check it out.

Comment: It's being generated by the jQuery

Comment: I looked all over my code and didn't find anywhere `256px` for any height. Would you mind elaborating?